# How to submit the correct div elements (not the div that's hidden)?

Tags: jquery, hide

I have the following code working fine but the problem is that it always submits the first div (article) even though it's hidden.  My question is how do I submit the form and the elements in the form in the div that's shown?  (if I select Music radiobutton, I want to submit the input elements of the Music Div not the Article div.  Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='itemlist']").click(function() {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        $("div.box").hide();
        $("#"+selection).show();
    });
});

 <!--radio buttons-->
 <div id="articleselection"><input name="itemlist" type="radio" value="article" /> Article/Book </div>
 <div id="musicselection"><input name="itemlist" type="radio" value="music" /> Music</div>


 <!--article div starts-->
 <div id="article" class="box">
 <table class="fieldgroup">
 <tr><td>Journal Title: <input id="JournalTitle" name="JournalTitle" type="text" size="60" class="f-name" tabindex="1" value="JournalTitle">
 </table>

 <table class="fieldgroup">
 <tr><td>Article Author: <input id="ArticleAuthor" name="ArticleAuthor" type="text" size="40" class="f-name" tabindex="2" value="<"ArticleAuthor"></td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>

 <!--music div starts-->
 <div id="music" class="box">
 <table class="fieldgroup">
 <tr><td>Music Title: <input id="Music Title" name="Music Title" type="text" size="60" class="f-name" tabindex="1" value="Music Title">
 </table>

 <table class="fieldgroup">
 <tr><td> Music Author: <input id="MusicAuthor" name="Music Author" type="text" size="40" class="f-name" tabindex="2" value="<"MusicAuthor"></td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the input elements in the div box that is hidden. When inputs are disabled they do not appear in the post.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("input[name$='itemlist']").click(function() { 
        var selection = $(this).val(); 
        $("div.box").hide(); 
        $("input, select, textarea", $("div.box")).attr("disabled", true);
        $("#"+selection).show(); 
        $("input, select, textarea", $("#"+selection)).attr("disabled", false);
    });
```

Comment: How do I disable the input elements in the div dynamically (based on which radiobutton is chosen)?

Comment: the code above disables the inputs in the hidden div like you requested. What else are you asking?

Comment: The code works fine except the radiobutton I chose also have all the input elements hidden.  I want to enable them (the input elements in the div box that I selected).

Comment: take a look at my modified answer.  I belive this is what you want.  Disable Inputs in the hidden divs and enable inputs in the visible div. Right?

Comment: Yes!!!  That's the one I've been looking for days!  Thank you so much.

**just had to delete an extra . after $("#"+selection)

Comment: yeah sorry about that..I always have typos... I corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$(...).remove()` to completely remove the elements from the DOM tree.

Alternatively, you can set the `<input>` elements to be disabled, which will prevent them from being submitted, like this:

```
$(...).find(':input').attr('disabled', true);
```

**EDIT**: You can remove all hidden `<input>` elements before the form is submitted like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() { 
    $(this).find(':input:hidden').remove();
});
```

Comment: I tried .remove() but when I click on the other radiobutton, it's not being displayed anymore.